# JavaFX not changing Scene background in Jar

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have 2 methods:

[image]

They seems to be working just fine, in development mode, but when I generate my jar, when I click on the button that calls the `switchToTranslation` method it does not change the background. I checked the jar file and it is there, the images.

I also have this in my CSS file:

```
#main{
    -fx-background-image: url("../images/mainBackground.jpg");
}
```

but it will get overwritten anyway once the user presses the button.

Comment: Try with the complete path  in css and Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fullPath) in source code

Comment: what do you mean ? complete path relative to my system or the root of the project?

Comment: The path from the root of your project instead of the path relative to Main.class